# Speed up px choropleth rendering or alternatives

Tags: python, geospatial, choropleth, plotly-express

How can I speed up the rendering for choropleth map? Any parameter or anything do you recommend? I just need a simple map colored by zip code. Thanks

```
@st.cache_data(ttl=60*60, show_spinner=False)
def load_geo_json():
    file_contents = open('assets/ct_geo.json', 'r')
    return json.loads(file_contents.read())

zipcodes = load_geo_json()

fig = px.choropleth(df_active_num_dynamic, 
                                geojson=zipcodes, 
                                locations='postalcode', 
                                color='Active',
                                color_continuous_scale="Sunset",
                                range_color=(0, df_active_num_dynamic['Active'].max()),
                                featureidkey="properties.ZCTA5CE10",
                                scope="usa",
                                custom_data=["postalcode", "Active", "city",]
                                # labels={'Active':'# of Active Listings'}
                                )

            fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
            fig.update_traces(
                hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                    "Zip Code: %{customdata[0]}",
                    "# of Actives: %{customdata[1]}",
                    "City: %{customdata[2]}",
                ])
            )

            fig.update_layout(height=500, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
            st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```